# Where is the metadata robots no index, no follow in my wordpress site comming from?

Tags: wordpress, seo

This is my wordpress site: linearedge.com

If you check the source code you will find:

```
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots">
```

I'm not using ANY SEO plugin, so, where is this coming from? I also checked my header.php and that line isn't there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its getting put in there by the call to `wp_head()` in the `header.php` file of your theme.  Check your Search Engine Visibility setting (Settings > Reading). Make sure that box is unchecked.